# If comments are removed completely and not transferred to chat, is this fair if they contain useful advice?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

My comments were all removed under an answer to a question as someone decided they had become off-topic or there were too many of them. They were not transferred to chat. In fact, they were not off topic though there might have been to many of them.

Comment: I am asking a question because I feel that it is relevant to me. Why is it being downvoted? I notice, by the way, that everything I post on the French site is downvoted. It would seem there is some kind of bias.

Comment: Without more precision — i.e. which question it was — there is not much we can do to help you.

Comment: @Evpok Should I provide a link to the question then?

Comment: That would be a good start, yes.

Comment: @Evpok here it is: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24322/is-it-better-to-speak-formally-or-informally-generally

Comment: If you refer to the comments under [Jilliagre's answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/24327/82), they *were* moved to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52252/discussion-on-answer-by-jlliagre-is-it-better-to-speak-formally-or-informally-g), even though the tone of some of them is not really appropriate.

Comment: @Evpok Right. Well, when I went back there, that move to chat was not visible. Now, it is. Maybe the tone is not appropriate. I bend over backwards to provide reasonable advice based on personal experience and professional knowledge and sometimes it can be unnerving when everything one says which is perfectly admissible in most quarters is picked away at as if something untoward were being said. Thank you for your response.

Comment: For future reference : please don't “bend backward to provide reasonable advice” if it unnerves you.so much that you have trouble being civil.We do appreciate your contributions, so we'd rather avoid having to moderate them out for tone issues. (Other readers : this goes for you, too)

Comment: @Evpok  Ok, no extended discussion but I will say this. I do make an effort to "share my best" and I find that others ***sometimes*** don't like this. Read through the posts on this particular issue, you can see for yourself. Thank you.

Comment: I am posting here because this seems the only way to reach the moderators. You will see since you sent me that explanatory email, that I commented on the question: il lui arrive, etc. Have you seen what I said in my comment? It is perfectly reasonable, perfectly polite. Let's see if the OP responds. My bet is that she will not.